# How to filter API response based on multiple comma seprated value Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have businessGroup multiSelect dropdown in HTML, On checkbox multi value selection i am calling `getProductType()` function.

I am getting below value on multi-select dropdown selection

```
['Home Care', 'Personal Care']
```

Now I want to filter category based on businessGroup multiple value selection.

```
{    
    "productTypes": [
        {
            "businessGroup": "Home Care",
            "category": "Laundry"
        },
        {
            "businessGroup": "Personal Care",
            "category": "Skin Cleansing"
        }
    ]
}
```

**For Ex -**

- If i select Home Care From dropdown, than it will return Laundry in
  result.
- If i select both  Home Care and Personal Care From dropdown, than it
  will return Laundry and Skin Cleansing.

Below is my code

```
getProductType(bigcChange = false) {
    try {
      const txtValue = this.makeLineForm.controls['businessGroup'].value.toLowerCase();
      if (txtValue !== '') {       
        this.productTypes = this.productResp.productTypes.filter(type => type.businessGroup.toLowerCase() === txtValue);        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  }
```

Can any one help me to get expected output.

Comment: The response itself, the type/format, is more important than its origin (_"API response"_). At least in this case. And its an array and not a _"comma separated value"_

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: NOTE: a multi-select dropdown  generally return an array with the elements selected, not a string separated by commas. Any way you should convert the value of the control in an array of string in lowerCase -if you get an array use map for do it, else use split to create the array-, filter knowing that type.bussinesGroup should be in the array -use indexOf or include- and finally map the filtered result to get only the category

Comment: @Andreas, I tried to use join like  let txtValue = newValue.join(','); bt it wont worked for me.

Comment: @Eliseo, Can you please help to correct the code.

Comment: @Eliseo, I am getting an array of comma seprated value like this on multi select dropdown ['Home Care', 'Personal Care']

Comment: Eliseo means something like this: this.productTypes = this.productResp.productTypes.filter(type => txtValue.includes(type.businessGroup.toLowerCase()).map(x=>x.category ); // txtValue being an array

Comment: type.businessGroup.toLowerCase() is not an array of string. You should calculate in an auxiliar variable an array with the values to lowerCase, but be sure if your this.makeLineForm.controls['businessGroup'].value is an array or a string

Answer (score 0):

Try using String.split and Array.includes.

```js
getProductTypes(bigcChange = false) {
  try {
    const txtValue = this.makeLineForm.controls['businessGroup'].value.toLowerCase();
    if (txtValue !== '') {
      const selectedBusinessGroups = txtValue.split(',');   
      this.productTypes = this.productResp.productTypes.filter(
        type => selectedBusinessGroups.includes(
          type.businessGroup.toLowerCase()
        )
      )      
    }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding this right? Are you getting the selected business groups as a comma-delimited string? Or is txtValue actually an array of strings?

Comment: my txtvalue is like array of comma seprated string. Ex - ['Home Care', 'Personal Care']